# what is the best way to merge the double vertices lines in a plane to sphere object without loosing the plane UV map setting?

Tags: uv

when i use the self created plane to sphere object , i still have to deal with the double lines from start to end borders from the original bent plane .
in the picture we can see the lines are double where they will touch eachother.

in the second picture we see the final result with the sphere using the plane uv map, 
now is that still available when the double start to end border lines are merged ?

or is this impossible ?

what is the best way to merge these double lines and still have the plane uv map working?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>W</kbd>>*Remove doubles* to join them. Next, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>>*Mark seem* along the verts to allow for separation, basically joined edges will always remain connected, messing up your UV map, unless you specify otherwise with mark seem. Finally select everything in the UV image editor and hit <kbd>P</kbd> for pin to lock 'em in place. When you UV unwrap again, everything will be in order.

Comment: i works great , thanks but i have one more question about your answer, i have exported the file , and imported it in a new project , i took a look at the uv map , and it was exactly how i hoped it would be, it is the uv map from the plane, perfect ok , but if i change the uv map for a moment to see another setting or possibility , it seems i have lost the plane uvmap , and i can only get it back by redo my steps , or is there another way to get the plane uvmap back to where it was , after i changed it for another unwrap ?

Comment: also could you say "Mark seem along the verts to allow for separation."in other words ? i try to understand what you mean exactly. specially the part :" allow for separation"

Comment: you made the answer as short as possible with a few words and i have to guess exactly what it means..

Comment: @elmentor What do you mean by "exported the file", did you save it or did you export it to another software package

Comment: i stay only in blender. i exported the file as an object in a folder and then imported that object again in blender to see what happens. and than like i said , i found out the uv map is lost at the moment i am trying another unwrap for experimental purpose. the only way to get my original uv map back is to redo my steps, or is there a way to recreate this uvmap again after when i changed it ?

Comment: @elmentor Are you exporting your UVmap? if you don't know how that would be a separate question. What does the UVmap look like when it is imported? What format are you using

Comment: for import/export i use object files only.  when the sphere object is imported , the attached uv map looks like a square , exactly like the plane. it stays like that as long i don't go experiment and try other unwraps. or the square uv map will then change into another  kind of form. after changing it now i want to go back to my square uvmap that i originally had, but the only way to get it back is to undo my steps , is that right or is there another way ? can i for example import a plane uv map into a sphere object ?

Comment: @elmentor Use p to pin them if you don't want them to change. The pinning isn't exported with the OBJ format, I would recommend not using it for transferring parts of blend files, use linking and appending. My answer cannot be expected to support export formats, it isn't possible to lock a UV through OBJ

Comment: i am gonna study how the pin has to be used exactly. i hope that is the solution i was looking for.

Comment: @elmentor This is the best possible solution you can get. If you export your UV map, it will change if you re-unwrap, since you simply cannot export the settings. Its simple: If you use .OBJ and you try to un wrap again, it will change

Comment: it makes sense that you loose the uvmap and cannot get it back in the square shape that you had before unless you do the undo steps to get back , and there is no other way to recreate them again. i understand. i might use the pin function as you say , but best of all , i suggest i just leave the uvmap at its square form , and not gonna touch it...that should be fine then.  thanks for explain.

Answer (score 0):

another handy way to move edges around on closed objects is edge slide with preserve UV checked.

It helps in cases *Almost like this....

Fiddling with edges on a closed shape to hand decimate.

Comment: i didn't understand this edge slide solution , but never mind , the first answer totally worked for me.  ("W"to remove doubles and Ctrl E ,mark seem etc )